# Convert JSON response into JAVA Object

Tags: android, json, gson

I am trying to read a JSON file to convert it into a Java object but I am getting an error. This JSON response code is from an API. Here is my Main activity.This is the first time I am asking a question so please help me.

```
package com.example.ahsan.jsontogson;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String mPath = "Json.txt";
private QuoteBank mQuoteBank;
private List<String> mLines;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // 1. i am getting error on this line source file is not located error
    QuoteBank staff = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\JSON.txt"),    QuoteBank.class);
    // 2. JSON to Java object, read it from a Json String.
    String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";
    Staff staff = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Staff.class);
    // JSON to JsonElement, convert to String later.
    JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.Json"), JsonElement.class);
    String result = gson.toJson(json);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I have also included GSON dependency in gradle file

Comment: What is the error which you are getting. Please add logs.

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
` in your `Manifest`.

Comment: Yeah Thanks I have done it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that you are trying to read that file from your device which is on your desktop/laptop.

```
 QuoteBank staff = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\JSON.txt"),    QuoteBank.class); //D drive path
```

And you cannot do so like this in any way. 
The file should be present somewhere in your device external storage directory.